# Tableau calculated column based on another column

Tags: tableau-api

The following Tableau calculated field calculates properly for my entire dataset: sum([Total Risk])/sum([TotalACV])

However, there is an additional column called AccountNumber - there are 9000 unique account numbers in my data set and multiple entries per Account Number.

I would like to change the calculation above so it calculates based on the individual AccountNumber, not the entire data set.

Answer (score 0):

{FIXED([AccountNumber]) : ([Account Risk %])}